# IsapiRewrite rules generate strange pages/folders?

Tags: isapi-rewrite, helicontech

i'm using IsapiRewrite from helicontech for my custom classic ASP shopping cart.
My actual httpd.ini file is:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %HTTPS off
RewriteCond Host: (?!^www.domain.com)(.+)
RewriteRule /(.*) http\://www.domain.com/$2 [I,RP]
RewriteRule /httpd(?:\.ini|\.parse\.errors).* / [I,O]
RewriteRule /(.+)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /detail.asp?brand=$1&model=$2&id=$3&lg=$4 [L]
```

So i'm actually using this component only to rewrite the product detail page in a nice way.
Lately looking in google cache i find some folders with files inside cached by googleBot that doesn't exist on my server eg: domain.com/carrera-CHAMPION ... and so on.
The page drawn if i access these strange pages is the detail.asp page but without css and some js loaded.
I tested recently the site with Acunetix scanner and seems like he found too these strange folders.
First i added a javascript check to se if Jquery not loaded then that means the page is one of these so i throw an alert and redirect user to homepage ..
Do you know what could be ? or how i could solve this via a rule in httpd.ini?

Hope i make myself clear if no feel free to ask me details,
thank you

Comment: forgot to mention is the PRO version of Isapirewrite not the litle one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that when you disable ISAPI_Rewrite these strange pages/folders disappear?
Please note that ISAPI_Rewrite only rewrites response headers and can't generate anything, so it's highly unlikely to be the cause of the issue.

BTW, your config is the mixture of ISAPI_Rewrite 2 and 3 syntax. If it's v2, please fix it like this:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteCond %HTTPS off
RewriteCond Host: (?!www.domain.com).+
RewriteRule /(.*) http\://www.domain.com/$1 [I,RP]
RewriteRule /httpd(?:\.ini|\.parse\.errors).* / [I,O]
RewriteRule /(.+)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /detail.asp\?brand=$1&model=$2&id=$3&lg=$4 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, changed the httpd.ini file as you told me .. working but no difference .. the strange pages still appear .I disabled the URL rewrite and the detail page throw 404 and the strange page the same ... a correct detail page is : www.domain.com/Christian Dior-MYMISS DIOR 2-10762-en.html a strange page example is www.domain.com/Carrera-ENDURANCE/Christian Dior-MYMISS DIOR 2-10762-en.html  so somehow is added that extra folder called Carrera-ENDURANCE .. without that the url is correct ..

Comment: how could i stop appearing these folders in url? The rule allow me to add there www.domain.com/blablabla/Christian Dior-MYMISS DIOR 2-10762-en.html i need to remove rendering these extra url's, already google index have a lot of these strange url's, thanks